# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() - Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

**Este es mi controlador:**

```
public function index()
{
    $almacenes = Almacen::with('actividades:id,nombre')->orderBy('id')->get();
    return view("almacen.index", compact('almacenes'));
}
```

**Y esta es la vista:**

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($almacenes as $almacen)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $almacen->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $almacen->nombrecom }}</td>
        <td>{{ $almacen->nit }}</td>
        <td>{{ $almacen->direccion }}</td>
        <td>
            @foreach ($almacen->actividades as $actividad)
                {{ $loop->last ? $actividad->nombre : $actividad->nombre.", " }}
            @endforeach
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

**La cosa es que tengo un código prácticamente idéntico que funciona perfecto. Es este:**
**Controlador:**

```
public function index()
{
    $datas = Usuario::with('roles:id,nombre')->orderBy('id')->get();
    return view('admin.usuario.index', compact('datas'));
}
```

**La vista:**

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($datas as $data)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $data->usuario }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->nombre }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->email }}</td>
        <td>
            @foreach ($data->roles as $rol)
                {{ $loop->last ? $rol->nombre : $rol->nombre.", " }}
            @endforeach
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

No entiendo por qué no devuelve lo que necesito. Corro un `dd($almacenes)` y todo está en orden, incluyendo las relaciones con el modelo *Actividad*. Gracias!

Comment: Shaz, algunos no tienen actividades! Cómo procedo ahí?

Comment: Así es, sí funciona. Aún sin tocar el with() en el controlador el código se ejecuta sin problema. Es cuando voy a usar el foreach().

Comment: Bueno, creo que no me hice entender, o tu respuesta no fue clara... ¿cuál de los dos foreach no funciona? yo me refiero a quitar temporalmente solo el foreach de actividades y probar, con el fin de intentar aislar el problema e identificarlo.

Comment: El foreach de actividades es el que quité. El de los demás datos del almacén sí funciona, hasta que vuelvo a poner el de actividades y devuelve el error.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer no todos tus almacenes tienen actividades, para lo cual puedes probar con forelse, para que no haya error en dicho caso:

```
        @forelse ($almacen->actividades as $actividad)
            {{ $loop->last ? $actividad->nombre : $actividad->nombre.", " }}
        @empty
            No hay actividades
        @endforelse
```

Si por algún motivo no funcionara, o desees hacerlo de forma distinta según el fin de tu código, puedes simplemente comprobar primero que la relación exista y que no esté vacía:

```
@if(!$almacen->actividades->isEmpty())
    @foreach ($almacen->actividades as $actividad)
        {{ $loop->last ? $actividad->nombre : $actividad->nombre.", " }}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: He probado ambos códigos. Laravel devuelve el mismo error...
```Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\laragon\www\Proyecto\resources\views\almacen\index.blade.php)```

Comment: Revisa y prueba la modificación que le hice al segundo código.

Answer (score 0):

yo lo que hago es lo siguiente, verifico si la relación tiene datos, si es asi los muestro en caso contrario no entrará al foreach, el isset lo que hace es comprobar si la variable existe

```
<td>
   @if(isset($almacen->actividades))
     @foreach ($almacen->actividades as $actividad)
       {{ $loop->last ? $actividad->nombre : $actividad->nombre.", " }}
     @endforeach
   @endif
</td>
```

Answer (score -2):

Resuelto! El problema era que la tabla *Almacen* también tenía una columna llamada *actividades*. Esta era la que capturaba el controlador en lugar del array de la relación. Ajusté el modelo, el controlador y la tabla para descartar esa tabla, y asunto arreglado! Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Shaz!